# Django: query various objects in a loop

Tags: python, django

I have a (duplicate detection) query in Django that I want to apply for several models:

```
Cooperation.objects.values('seo__slug').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('seo__slug).filter(count__gt=1)
Article.objects.values('seo__slug').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('seo__slug).filter(count__gt=1)
City.objects.values('seo__slug').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('seo__slug).filter(count__gt=1)
```

Is there a coding concept so that I can do this in a loop.
e.g (Pseudo Code, this below is not working)

```
information_objects = ['Cooperation', 'Article', 'City']
for obj in information_objects:
  obj.objects.values('seo__slug').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('seo__slug).filter(count__gt=1)
```

I hope I can get my question across.
If anybody can tell me if this concept is supported in Django please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the list contain the actual classes, then your code will work:

```
information_objects = [Cooperation, Article, City]
```

If you absolutely need to get them based on strings, you can get the classes from `globals()`:

```
information_objects = [globals()[name] for name in ('Cooperation', 'Article', 'City')]
```

or use getattr if they are in a specific module:

```
information_objects = [getattr(the_module, name) for name in ('Cooperation', 'Article', 'City')]
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!